# how to delete all records from the table using entityframework in mvc

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I want to delete all the records of the table. I am able to delete based on id, but I don't want based on id. My sql server table name is `[EnergyMonitoringDB].[dbo].[Energies]` How to delete it.

The code:

```cs
public string Delete_AllEnergyData() {
          using (EnergyMonitoringDBEntities Obj = new EnergyMonitoringDBEntities())
          {
                Obj.Energies.RemoveRange(Obj.Energies);
                Obj.SaveChanges();
                return "Energy Data Deleted Successfully";
          }
}
```

AngularJS code:

```js
$scope.DeleteAll = function () {
       $http({
           method: "post",
           url: "http://localhost:3523/Admin/Home/Delete_AllEnergyData",
           datatype: "json",
           data: JSON.stringify(Emp)
       }).then(function (response) {
           alert(response.data);
           $scope.GetAllData();
       })
   };
```

html code:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete All" ng-click="DeleteAll()" />
```

Comment: `Obj.Energies.RemoveRange(Obj.Energies); Obj.SaveChanges();` does this not work?

Comment: its working . problem is in front end. button event is nt firing. the controller able to delete records. error angular.min.js:62 ReferenceError: Emp is not defined

Comment: Your function does not have any parameter. So remove sending parameter `data: JSON.stringify(Emp)` to controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Delete_AllEnergyData` does not have any parameter. So remove sending parameter `data: JSON.stringify(Emp)` to controller as following:

```
$scope.DeleteAll = function () {
        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:3523/Admin/Home/Delete_AllEnergyData",
        }).then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data);
            $scope.GetAllData();
        })
    };
```